# hook_menu_alter or hook_menu_link_alter?

Tags: drupal, menu, hook

How to alter custom menu in hook_menu_link_alter?
I use next code:

```
function MY_MODULE_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
    // here some code
}
```

this function not working to menu created in admin panel (/admin/structure/menu/add).
But working normaly to menu created by module admin_menu (/admin/structure/menu/manage/management).
Where problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)(). This hook alters the data being saved to `menu_router` table after [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) is invoked.

Comment: function custom_menu_menu_alter(&$items) {
 $items['node/2']['title'] = 'Changed title';
}

Not changed in link on node with nid 2=(

Comment: Where exactly you wanna show 'Changed title'?! In a menu link or in node page ?!

Comment: In menu link. I have menu in footer, need there change title and path by hook

Comment: why don't you use the menu UI from `admin/structure/menu/manage/[MENU_ID]` to change the title?!

Comment: if user logged, need change title in link.

Answer (score 6):

**hook_menu_alter()** -> Alter the data being saved to the {menu_router} table after hook_menu is invoked. So by using this hook you can alter like -

access_callback,
   access_arguments,
   page_callback,
   page_arguments,
   delivery_callback,
   title,
   title_callback,
   title_arguments,
   theme_callback and so on.

**hook_menu_link_alter()** -> Alter the data being saved to the {menu_links} table. So by using this hook you can alter like -

link_path,
   router_path,
   hidden,
   link_title and so on.